# Maximum number of nodes in a Huffman tree

Tags: binary-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation, huffman-code, treenode

For the purpose of memory performance optimizations while building a Huffman tree I would like to pre-allocate the necessary memory for its nodes.

Is there a way to calculate the maximum number of nodes (internal nodes plus leafs)?

Input for the calculation should be the table of symbols and their probabilities/frequencies. I would like to avoid a simulated tree building run. Instead it should be a plain calculation that must not give the actual/optimal number of nodes but a reliable maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are *n* symbols, then there are *n-1* internal nodes, or *2n-1* internal nodes and leaves, or what you're calling nodes. It's always exactly that — not a "maximum".